# Do SharePoint 2013's RESTful services support querying multi-level relationship properties?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, odata, sharepoint-2013

This is a hypothetical situation to illustrate the problem. I realize that this could likely be solved another way.

There are 3 SharePoint Lists:
**PersonList** -
--Name
-- AddressLookupColumn
**AddressList**-
-- Address
-- AddressTypeLookupColumn
**AddressTypeList**-
-- AddressTypeName

Using the OData spec I can do something like:

```
http://mysite/_api/web/getByTitle('PersonList')/items?$select=Name,AddressLookupColumn/Address&$expand=AddressLookupColumn
```

That will give me *Name and Address*. What I need is the Name, Address, and Address Type.

I think should be able to do:

```
http://mysite/_api/web/getByTitle('PersonList')/items?$select=Name,AddressLookupColumn/Address,AddressLookupColumn/AddressTypeLookupColumn/AddressTypeName&$expand=AddressLookupColumn,AddressLookupColumn/AddressTypeLookupColumn
```

.. in order to get *Name, Address, and AddressTypeName*

Does SharePoint support that? If so, what am I doing wrong in my query?

Comment: `AddressTypeList` is not linked directly to the list queried in the first place (`PersonList`) so I don't think this is possible without having two queries

Answer (score 0):

`AddressTypeList` is not linked directly to the list queried in the first place (`PersonList`) so the answer is no, you would need an extra query to get the third level of information.